# GXT GridInlineEditing field validation

Tags: java, validation, gwt, gxt, inline-editing

I am building an editor application using GWT/GXT with gwt editor framework. For some cases I have to edit a list of dates. To do so I chose to use `GridInlineEditing`, it works fine, but I also have to make some format validation on my `DateField` inside the gridInlineEditing.

Basically, the default behavior of the editing is to "record" changes when `CompleteEditEvent` is fired regardless the result of the validation. I therefore tried to override the `onCompleteEditHandler` method like this (which obviously is the only way to do it [according to GXT forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?255907-Validation-in-GridInlineEditing)):

```
public class NameValueDTMEditorWidget extends GenericEditableListView<DTM, Date> implements Editor<NameValueDTM> {
private final static DTMProperties props = GWT.create(DTMProperties.class);

ListStoreEditor<DTM> values;
@Ignore
private DateField df = new DateField();

public NameValueDTMEditorWidget(String widgetTitle) {
    super(widgetTitle, new ListStore<DTM>(props.key()), props.dtm());

    DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

    df.setPropertyEditor(new DateTimePropertyEditor(dtf));

    addEditorConfig(df); // parent class method basically doing: editing.addEditor(df), editing is GridInlineEditing

    // Modifying grid cell render for a Date
    Cell c = new DateCell(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCell(c);

    values = new ListStoreEditor<DTM>(getStore());

    editing.addCompleteEditHandler(new CompleteEditEvent.CompleteEditHandler<DTM>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleteEdit(CompleteEditEvent<DTM> event) {
            df.validate(); // I force field validation
            if (df.getValue() == null || !df.isValid()) { // if value's not valid
                getStore().clear(); // clear the store
                DTM e = GWT.create(DTM.class);
                getStore().add(e); // add a new value
                editing.startEditing(event.getEditCell()); // start editing new value
                df.forceInvalid(); // force invalid to get invilid display on the field
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It does almost what I want, it stays in edition when value is not valid and everything, but when I input a valid value after a wrong one it knows the value is valid but it does not exit edition mode. I have also tried to do the samething keeping the wrong inputed value instead of clearing my store and creating a new value and it behaves exactly the same way, except that with this method I also have a display problem.

Does anybody know how to do this? I also have the same problem with a list of `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Converter

```
    editing.addEditor(columnConfig, new Converter<String, Date>() {

        @Override
        public String convertFieldValue(Date date) { /* called when you leave the cell */
            GridCell cell = (GridCell) editing.getActiveCell();
            ListStore<DTM> store = grid.getStore();
            DTM dtm = store.get(cell.getRow());

            /*
             * here you have the dtm object belongs to related cell and the date as input.
             * done with your validation here.
             */

            return dtf.format(date);
        }

        @Override
        public Date convertModelValue(String date) { /* called when you focus in the cell */
            return dtf.parse(date);
        }

    }, df);
```

Comment: I have been switch to another project for now but as soon as I get back to this one, I will tell you if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Field#clearInvalid` before validating the field (I think this would be done before the `df.validate();` line in your example).

Comment: I still have the exact same behavior. I guess the problem is more related to the GridInlineEditing than to the field or the field validation itself.